# Best practice for passing directory locations between R packages

Tags: r, caching, package

What is best-practice for locating a large file which is passed between projects and packages?

I have an R project, `ccBasics`, with same-named package. The source files live in `~/ccBasics` .  Its scripts produce a 100MB+ file, `bigFile.rds`. My other packages, which import ccBasics, use `bigFile.rds`.

When I placed `bigFile.rds` in `~/ccBasics/data/`, it made building ccBasics very slow, as bigFile gets copied over to `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/ccBasics/data`.  So I put the file in `/ccBasics/cache/` and created a function

```
@export
getBigfile <- function(){
  readRDS("~/ccBasics/cache/bigFile.rds")
}
```

This has worked fine for my development, but it breaks if someone else wants to install `ccBasics` in, say, `/usr/local/ccBasics`.  I'd hoped that `find.package("ccBasics")` or `path.package()` would help, but they return the location of where `ccBasics` is built. And if I initially write the file to  `~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/ccBasics/data` then it gets clobbered when I rebuild.

So what's best practice  I've thought of some workarounds

- Creating a `ccBasicsCache` project and only rebuilding it when `bigFile` changes
- Creating a configuration file, `fileLocation.yaml` which each installation would edit.

But they seem ugly.  What is standard practice for this?

Comment: Asking for "best practices" is really just a matter of opinion and such questions are off topic. It's better to state specific requirements that can be used to evaluate possible solutions. There's not really one "right" way to store data. It all depends on the needs of the project. Most likely there will have to be some configuration you set up somewhere to account for different systems. Packages work best to organize code. They are less good at managing data.

Comment: Agree with MrFlick, this is my opinion (before this question may get closed). I've seen packages that intentionally split into a code package and one for largeish slow-to-change data. For instance, create a `ccBasics.data` package that only has the large `.rds` file, either as literal data that `data("bigFile", package="ccBasics.data")` can find, or `system.file("bigFile.rds", package="ccBasics.data")` and then `readRDS` that way. Add `Imports: ccBasics.data` to your code-package `ccBasics`.